# How to get the message from a Java exception caught in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am attempting to catch exceptions being thrown by Java and report the exception message to my own logging framework. However, if I do this, there's an obvious chicken-and-egg problem; I'm trying to get the message using the Java `getMessage()` call:

```
jthrowable e = env->ExceptionOccurred();
jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(e);
jmethodID getMessage = env->GetMethodID(clazz,
                                        "getMessage",
                                        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

but I can't actually resolve getMessage, because the pending exception causes the JVM to abort when I call `GetObjectClass`.

Is there a safe way to get the `jmethodID` for all exceptions up-front? If I Just get the method ID for `Throwable.getMessage()` at application startup, will that `jmethodID` be portable to other classes?  Or is the appropriate approach to call `env->ExceptionClear()` and just keep on using the same local jthrowable reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The below works; however, I don't know if it's the intended-correct approach:

```
jthrowable e = env->ExceptionOccurred();
env->ExceptionClear(); // clears the exception; e seems to remain valid

jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(e);
jmethodID getMessage = env->GetMethodID(clazz,
                                        "getMessage",
                                        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring message = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(e.get(), getMessage);
const char *mstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(message, NULL);
// do whatever with mstr
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(message, mstr);
env->DeleteLocalRef(message);
env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
env->DeleteLocalRef(e);
```

Comment: You don't really need all those `DeleteLocalRef()` calls unless the method goes on to use lots of others. The references will be deleted when the JNI method exits. +1

Comment: @EJP True in general, but since this is a thing that's calling other things and eating the exceptions it throws, it's not even remotely certain that it'll be exiting back to Java control. In my actual code I wrap localrefs up in scope-lifetime wrappers so that's automatic anyway, and I figure it's better to provide fully-correct example code in solutions. :)

Comment: (Also, I'm used to doing this stuff on Android, where the JNI implementation is extremely aggressive about killing the process if it has too many localrefs or even globalrefs open, because it's being "helpful" in detecting a "leak.")

Comment: You DO need to call DeleteLocalRef() if the native code is the root frame on the stack, because it will never return to Java.  This happens if you have a native EXE embedding a JVM, or you create native threads in a Java application.  However, you usually do not need to delete classes or methods, because they are static.